# How to make new timeseries based on previous value in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

this is my first question on stack overflow so the formatting might be a bit off. I have a problem that I know a solution for with a for loop in python. However, I don't know if there is a way in pandas itself that does the same thing faster.

Problem:
Suppose I have a pandas Series 'in' consisting of an index date and where every date has a value (integer). There is also a Series 'out' that has the same structure.

Ex:

```
in
date         val
2022-12-01   5
2022-12-02   8
2022-12-03   19
```

```
out
date         val
2022-12-01   3
2022-12-02   7
2022-12-03   21
```

If I want to make a Series of the amount of events that are being processed each day, I could do it with a for loop in the following where the value of every day is open.iloc[i]=open[i-1]+in[i]-out[i]. The result should be

```
open
date         val
2022-12-01   2    #5-3
2022-12-02   3    #2+8-7
2022-12-03   1    #3+19-21
```

Is there a way to do this in pandas itself, without the need for a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

##### new answer

Use [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
ser_open = ser_in.sub(ser_out).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
2022-12-01    2
2022-12-02    3
2022-12-03    1
dtype: int64
```

Used input:

```
ser_in = pd.Series([5, 8, 19], index=['2022-12-01', '2022-12-02', '2022-12-03'])
ser_out = pd.Series([3, 7, 21], index=['2022-12-01', '2022-12-02', '2022-12-03'])
```

##### initial answer

Use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) after setting `date` as index:

```
out = (df_open
 .set_index('date').shift()
 .add(df_in.set_index('date')-df_out.set_index('date'),
      fill_value=0
     )
 .reset_index()
)
```

Or, for assignment use variant with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df_open['val'] = df_open['date'].map(df_open
 .set_index('date').shift()
 .add(df_in.set_index('date')-df_out.set_index('date'),
      fill_value=0
     )['val']
)
```

Output:

```
         date  val
0  2022-12-01  2.0
1  2022-12-02  3.0
2  2022-12-03  1.0
```

Used inputs:

```
df_in = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2022-12-01', '2022-12-02', '2022-12-03'], 'val': [5, 8, 19]})
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2022-12-01', '2022-12-02', '2022-12-03'], 'val': [3, 7, 21]})
df_open = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2022-12-01', '2022-12-02', '2022-12-03'], 'val': [2.0, 3.0, 1.0]})
```

Comment: Thank you! I had already come across the shift method, but I made a mistake in the question. Sorry for that, it has already been corrected. It weren't Dataframes, but Series.

Comment: How have you defined df_open by the way? I can't really make it work.

Comment: @Wannes see update, but best if **you** provide the constructors (`pd.Series(…)`/`pd.DataFrame(…)`) for your inputs

Comment: I read again and provided an alternative interpretation of the question, which I think is what you want.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I forgot about cumsum.